# Android \n newline is escaped in textview

Tags: java, php, android

I have `echo $result` in PHP code and I am printing the result to a textview and I want to display it in multiline but I get this in the textView

```
Available articles: 28
---------------------------------------
number of clients: 23
Top solded Articles and its beneficient:
Muffin Mix - Lemon Cranberry:161.41
Mushrooms - Black, Dried:148.62
Amaretto:134.01
Longos - Grilled Veg Sandwiches:122.89
```

Here is my android code

```
public void processFinish(String output) {
    TextView reprttxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.reprttxt);
    output.replace("\\n",System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    reprttxt.setText(output);
}
```

Notice that I tried `output.replace("\\n",System.getProperty("line.separator"));` and `output.replace("\\\n",System.getProperty("line.separator"));` but it doesn't work. How to solve that by modifying the Android Java code or the PHP code?

Comment: Try replacing `\n`, not `\\n`

Comment: sorry , dont work

Comment: `echo -e "$result"` or `printf "$result"`?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CharSquence` instead of a `String` for `output`. `TextView.setText()` doesn't like `String` text that contains special characters it will either strip it or display it weirdly depending on the circumstance `CharSquence` doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://android--examples.blogspot.com/2015/01/textview-new-line-multiline-in-android.html) doc you have to set a property like `android:maxLines="2"`. You can set any value you like. Then `'\n'` should work as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

The string doesn't have a real embedded newline `'\n'` character.  It has a `"\\n"` substring-  an actual backslash followed by an n.  The correct way to fix this is by fixing the server-  it shouldn't be sending the data like this.  If you need a hack, replace `"\\n"`, not `"\n"`

You can tell this is the case by the fact a `\n` is in the actual output.  If it was just the wrong type of separator, it would either be whitespace or ignored instead.  BTW, on Android the line separator is `'\n'` as it is on all Linux based systems.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void processFinish(String output) {
    TextView reprttxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.reprttxt);

    reprttxt.setText(Html.fromHtml(output));
}
```

example : output = "this is \n two line";